# Differentiating between the two grid systems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I was searching for the range of widths of the bootstraps columns and [this link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) gives me a list of one thresholds whereas [this one](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)  says otherwise.

You can scroll down a little there you will see the grid options and the values for the widths of the grids.

What is the difference between the two grid systems? More appropriately how have I failed to understand the difference between the two? Thanks.

Comment: I have reworded my question. Can you guys check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has a very good grid architecture. However the stable version is the first one. [click here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

and the alpha bootstrap is optimized with respect to latest browsers and updated with new components. For eg: Alpha bootstrap doesn't support for IE8, All the scripts are re-written in ES6, thumbnails are replaced by cards etc [read here for more information](https://www.gavick.com/blog/bootstrap-4-alpha-features)

You may use the [stable version](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) if you would like to have a cross browser support. Alpha bootstrap has more advance components made using flex box that doesn't support in older browsers.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Currently I am importing the bootstraps from here 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'

Comment: Not sure but I am not able to open that link. it says access denied. Strange!!!

Comment: I was editing maybe that's why. I assume it is not the alpha version because I checked the thresholds. However could you confirm it for me thanks.

Comment: Nope it still says access denied. https://postimg.org/image/ck3uwwzen/

Comment: I think you copied the inverted comma as well ( ' ) that is why it says access denied. Try removing the inverted comma from the url i should work.

Comment: Opps sorry I had inverted commas (') at the end of the url. Its working fine.

Comment: When you open the link by opening the url there will be an inverted comma at the end. Remove it and it should work.